Rstudio and Snowflake Help, dbGetQuery not working when trying to run Where clause
I am trying to pull in a snowflake table with a where clause where the "Snapshot_Date" is a date and "Date1" is a data value I set earlier in the R code.
However, this statement is returning a blank output. I know this is because something is wrong with the where clause, but iI can't get the where clause to work as intended.
date1 <- "2024-03-02"

file1 <- ddbGetQuery(myconn,paste("
SELECT
Year,Month, Origin, CAST(Snapshot_Date as Date) as Snapshot_Date
FROM SNOWFLAKE_TABLE
WHERE CAST(Snapshot_Date as date)  = '", date1,"'"))

I am expecting the file1 data to be filtered for snapshot_dates that are = to "2024-03-02"

Welcome to SO, Maggie Schroeder! This statement does not parse, you have unmatched double-quotes at a minimum. It can be difficult helping on questions where it seems clear that you have not tried the code you have given us, meaning we have to somehow guess which errors/problems are real, and which are typos ... and then infer what you intend the code to be. Please try your own code, fix it for the parsing errors, then [edit] your question and provide the fixed code in its [code block].

@r2evans my apologies for the quote error, i had been testing out single vs. double quotes to see if i could work around the issue. I have edited the code to reflect the current code i am trying to run. The SNOWFLAKE_Table is a table i am directly connected to earlier in the code through dbConnect. The date1 is a single input that is updated to the date we are trying to filter the code for. I am trying to get the data from snowflake to only return data where the  snapshot_date = date1 which is set as "2024-03-02".

(1) Still [code block]s when editing questions, it is usually very difficult to read/interpret code that the web interface auto-wraps and drops indenting, and very helpful when it is formatted in fixed-width indent-preserving format that many (most?) expect. Aesthetics really help here. (2) Does my answer work for you?

You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about malicious SQL injection (e.g., XKCD's Exploits of a Mom aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. DBI supports parameterized queries.
Even though your expression here does not parse (so it's clearly not your real code), I think what you need is something like this:
file1 <- dbGetQuery(myconn, "
    SELECT Year, Month, Origin, CAST(Snapshot_Date as Date) as Snapshop_Date
    FROM SNOWFLAKE_TABLE
    WHERE CAST(Snapshot_Date as Date) = ?",
  params = list(date1))

Assuming that date1 and Snapshot_Date look like dates (e.g., "2024-04-02"), then you don't need the CAST(.), most databases will do what you need. (Even if they don't infer it's a date, if it is a string and you do a string comparison, is there a problem?)
file1 <- dbGetQuery(myconn, "
    SELECT Year, Month, Origin, CAST(Snapshot_Date as Date) as Snapshop_Date
    FROM SNOWFLAKE_TABLE
    WHERE Snapshot_Date = ?",
  params = list(date1))

The need for the selecting CAST(.) is questionable, but since I don't have your database I can't be sure.

running this code: file1 <- dbGetQuery(myconn, "
SELECT Year, Month, Origin, CAST(Snapshot_Date as Date) as Snapshop_Date
FROM SNOWFLAKE_TABLE
WHERE Snapshot_Date = ?",
params = list(date1))
returns file1 to have 4 variables, but no data populated in the columns. Which im fairly certain is due to the date filtering

It might be helpful to me if you post the output from "SELECT Snapshot_Date from SNOWFLAKE_TABLE LIMIT 4" into a [code block] in your original question; if the formatting is off then my assumptions will not be correct.
